# Perspective Crop with CSS3

Tags: html, css, crop

I want to create a perspective crop like effect with CSS3 like this: 
[image]

I did try it doing my self but couldn't, any help would be appreciated.

here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/y9eusob9/

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="container">
       <img src="http://img.netcarshow.com/Lotus-Evora_GX_Racecar_2013_1600x1200_wallpaper_01.jpg" alt="main image" />
   </div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS Code:

```
.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Post the code! Show what you've already tried!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/y9eusob9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to add a container `<div>`, e.g.`.perspective`, that gets the yellow background color and to use a polygon `clip-path` on the image.

A good tool to create these polygons is [Bennett Feely's clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/). [Browser support for clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) isn't quite there yet though. See [Clipping and Masking in CSS](http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) for more background information and options.

```css
.perspective {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
  
.perspective__image {
  display: block;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 20%, 90% 10%, 90% 90%, 10% 80%);
  clip-path: polygon(10% 20%, 90% 10%, 90% 90%, 10% 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective">
  <img src="http://www.nicenicejpg.com/400/300" class="perspective__image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a ton for the answer, is it crossbroser compatible? IE9+, chrome, safari, firefox?

Comment: No unfortunately not, if you want it to be cross browser you can create a SVG image that includes your image.

Comment: thank you for the answer, unfortunately I need a slider in there, your method seems to work.

Comment: Another option would be to overlay an SVG with a transparent center on top of the image. I think that would work on IE9+.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to accomplish this effect using a layering technique like what is found here:

http://cssglobe.com/angled-content-mask-with-css/

Basically, the author used a few nested elements that were rotated back and forth with `overflow: hidden` on the container elements.

Answer (score 2):

For [maximum browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) you could use `svg`'s `clipPath`.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M50,50 L400,0 L400,400 L50,350" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject clip-path="url(#shape)" width="400" height="400">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400" />
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a great tutorial on css-tricks that talks about doing exactly this:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

You'll be making use of the `transform` property to make the rotations you need to simulate the perspective change.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.